# Какой шейдер использовать?

Tags: c#, unity3d, шейдеры

Шейдеры только начинаю изучать. Задача такая: у объекта есть полностью прозрачные и полностью непрозрачные части. Хочу через скрипт менять цвет непрозрачной части с помощью gameObject.GetComponent().material.color = Color.цвет;
Какой для этого нужно использовать шейдер?

Comment: а у меня 1 вопрос, Вы в документацию заглядывали? или в гугл?... сначала  идете в [документацию](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/500/Manual/Shaders.html), пробуете что то написать. Если не получилось копируете код, и конкретно по нему задаете вопрос.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, пардон, уточнил вопрос

Comment: Cutout шейдер идеально подходит вашим требованиям.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker наверное я что-то не понимаю, но ведь в Transparent Cutout нет поля color?

Comment: Вы точно стандартный шейдер смотрите? Только что проверил - все "обычные" свойства стандартный шейдер поддерживает, в том числе и цвет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на данный вопрос очень сильно зависит от версии Unity, хотя я в этом не сильно уверен - стандартный шейдер всегда поддерживал Cutout материалы.

В зависимости от выбранного шейдера пути у нас 2:

1. Standard shader
2. Legacy Transparent Cutout

---

### Standard shader

Просто создаем новый материал - Unity сам добавит к нему необходимый шейдер, все, что нам останется - указать, что нам нужен Cutout шейдер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее создадим cutout маску и наложим на нее текстуру:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вернемся к нашему материалу и укажем все настройки, в Albedo положим наше изображение выше и поменяем цвет на, к примеру, красный. После всех этих махинаций применим данный материал к стандартному Quad`у и получим такую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

### Legacy Transparent Cutout

Тут уже посложнее, создаем новый материал и вручную выбираем нужный нам шейдер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тут уже сами смотрите, какой конкретно Cutout шейдер вам нужен. В данном примере я выбрал Cutout Diffuse - самый "стандартный" шейдер, если его так можно назвать. Все остальное - навороты со всякими вкусностями, которые к вопросу не относятся.

---

Осталась мелочь - настроить наш материал:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Применим материал все к тому же Quad`у и получим следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]